# Silverlight: Last item in a ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I have an ItemsControl. For the last item in the ItemsControl I want to hide the TextBox containing the comma. Is there a way to do this using XAML?

```
        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource NotEmpty}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Answer}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
<TextBlock Text=", " Visibility="{Binding LastItemVisibility}" />
```

with in your view model something like

```
public Visibility LastItemVisibility
{
    get { return MyCollection.LastOrDefault() == this ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible; }
}
```

?

Comment: Now your ViewModel has to listen to change events on the collection that contains it. This isn't the end of the world, but it does get messy.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen yes that's true, but a little code is normal for most View Models. ;-) ... It's maybe a pity that there is no solution around for this quite common scenario. If there is only text like in your example, I'd probably use a simple `TextBlock` and a `ValueConverter` that does a `String.Join(...)` instead of an ItemsControl.

Comment: In real life I've got some funky formatting issues to work through. Otherwise I would have just make it a read-only property on the model or view-model.

Answer (score 1):

It's annoying it's not easier to solve this with a Converter. In fact if you could bind to the ConverterParameter (which is not possible in Silverlight v4) you could achieve what you want quite easily.

If you don't want to touch your model I think your best bet would be to create a new class derived from ControlControl which sets its own visibility based on the position of a bounditem in the itemssource. It's not the neatest solution in the world, but it keeps the model clean. It would look like this in the ItemsControl

```
  <local:ItemsControlVisibilityHelper ShowIfLast="False" ShowIfFirst="True"  ShowIfNotLastOrFirst="True"
                                                                    ItemsControl="{Binding ElementName=x_ItemsControl}"
                                                                    BoundItem="{Binding}"
                                                                    >
                                    <TextBlock Text=", "></TextBlock>
                                </local:ItemsControlVisibilityHelper>
```

Comment: That is certainly an interesting idea. I ended up rewriting the parent collection, but if I hadn't I would definitely try this.